# Why my build version of NestJS for production inside nx monorepo does not include database?

Tags: angular, deployment, nestjs, typeorm, monorepo

I created an nx monorepo (Angular + NestJS) with mysql database. Each time I build it for production using npx nx build or npx nx run api:build:production, I see success message (NX   SUCCESS  Running target "build" succeeded) and I see one folder for Angular and one for Api but I don't see any database related data like entity.js or so! I am trying do deploy my application to centos 7 using Plesk cpanel. But it seems that I do need to have a build version of database to proceed the migration.

the other thing I am confused about is that is uploading the build version of angular and nestjs  apps including database the only way of deployment or I can also upload the code to servr and then build that for production on the server?

I am new to nestjs and deployment.
Thanks for your help.

app.module.ts  (apps/api/src/app/)

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { EmailModule } from '@symbiota/api-email';
import { UserModule } from '@symbiota/api-user';
import { ApiAuthModule } from '@symbiota/api-auth';
import { ApiRoleModule } from '@symbiota/api-role';
import { ApiPermissionModule } from '@symbiota/api-permission';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import { PermissionGuard } from 'libs/api-permission/src/lib/api-permission.guard';

import config from '../../../../ormconfig';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    EmailModule,
    ApiAuthModule,
    ApiRoleModule,
    ApiPermissionModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(config),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: PermissionGuard,
    },
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

ormconfig.ts  (in root directory, same as package.json)

```js
import { MysqlConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlConnectionOptions';
import { Email } from './libs/api-email/src/lib/email.entity';
import { Permission } from './libs/api-permission/src/lib/api-permission.entity';
import { RoleEntity } from './libs/api-role/src/lib/api-role.entity';
import { User } from './libs/api-user/src/lib/user.entity';

const config: MysqlConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'test',
  entities: [Email, Permission, RoleEntity, User],
  synchronize: false,
};

export default config;
```

angular.json

```js
{
  "version": 1,
  "projects": {
    "api": {
      "root": "apps/api",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/api/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/api",
            "main": "apps/api/src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/api/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["apps/api/src/assets"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "inspect": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/api/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/api/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "api:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/api/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/api"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/api/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-auth": {
      "root": "libs/api-auth",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/api-auth/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/api-auth/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/api-auth"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/api-auth/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-common": {
      "root": "libs/api-common",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/api-common/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/api-common/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/api-common"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/api-common/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-email": {
      "root": "libs/api-email",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/api-email/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/api-email/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/api-email"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/api-email/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-interfaces": {
      "root": "libs/api-interfaces",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/api-interfaces/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/api-interfaces/**/*.ts"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-permission": {
      "root": "libs/api-permission",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/api-permission/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/api-permission/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/api-permission"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/api-permission/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-role": {
      "root": "libs/api-role",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/api-role/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/api-role/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/api-role"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/api-role/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-user": {
      "root": "libs/api-user",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/api-user/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/api-user/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/api-user"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/api-user/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "backend": {
      "root": "libs/backend",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/backend/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/backend/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/backend"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/backend/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "common": {
      "root": "libs/common",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/common/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/common/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/common"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/common/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "email": {
      "root": "libs/email",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/email/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/email/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/email"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/email/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "role": {
      "root": "libs/role",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/role/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/role/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/role"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/role/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "symbiota2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "apps/symbiota2",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/symbiota2/src",
      "prefix": "symbiota",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/symbiota2",
            "index": "apps/symbiota2/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/symbiota2/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/symbiota2/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/symbiota2/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "apps/symbiota2/src/favicon.ico",
              "apps/symbiota2/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": ["apps/symbiota2/src/styles.css"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "4mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "10kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/symbiota2/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/symbiota2/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "symbiota2:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "symbiota2:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "apps/symbiota2/proxy.conf.json"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "symbiota2:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "apps/symbiota2/src/**/*.ts",
              "apps/symbiota2/src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/symbiota2"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/symbiota2/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "symbiota2-e2e": {
      "root": "apps/symbiota2-e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/symbiota2-e2e/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
          "options": {
            "cypressConfig": "apps/symbiota2-e2e/cypress.json",
            "devServerTarget": "symbiota2:serve:development",
            "tsConfig": "apps/symbiota2-e2e/tsconfig.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "symbiota2:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/symbiota2-e2e/**/*.{js,ts}"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ui": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/ui",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/ui/src",
      "prefix": "symbiota",
      "architect": {
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/ui"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/ui/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/ui/src/**/*.ts", "libs/ui/src/**/*.html"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "user": {
      "root": "libs/user",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/user/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/user/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/user"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/user/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nrwl/angular",
    "packageManager": "npm"
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@nrwl/angular": {
      "application": {
        "linter": "eslint"
      },
      "library": {
        "linter": "eslint"
      },
      "storybook-configuration": {
        "linter": "eslint"
      }
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:application": {
      "style": "css",
      "linter": "eslint",
      "unitTestRunner": "jest",
      "e2eTestRunner": "cypress"
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:library": {
      "style": "css",
      "linter": "eslint",
      "unitTestRunner": "jest"
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:component": {
      "style": "css"
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "symbiota2"
}
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "symbiota",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "nx",
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.0",
    "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.6.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
    "@nrwl/angular": "12.9.0",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.5",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.38",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/jest": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/linter": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/nest": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/node": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/tao": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "12.9.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.24",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~4.28.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~4.28.3",
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jest": "27.0.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "9.0.7",
    "multer": "^1.4.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.3",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nx uses webpack by default, so you just get a single `dist/apps/api/main.js` or similar file that's used to start and run the server. This is why on Nest's site [it explicitly mentions that if you're using webpack to not use globs for entity files for TypeORM](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities)

Comment: Does the main.js file include database as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "include the database"? A database is usually a completely separate server, right?

Comment: Yes, I know little about these technologies actually. My end goal is to deploy Angular+nestjs with mysql database to server. How should I do that. and how should I configure the files to be able to do it?

Comment: it is my first time to deploy a nodejs application and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I tried to follow the link above which is the nestjs documentation but I get this error:

MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given.